# DBA Directories not able to access

Tags: oracle

Not able to access DBA_DIRECTORIES table.Getting an error message that table or view does not exist.
DBA said that he has given access to user however, still getting an error. I'm able to see result from ALL_DIRECTORIES but not from DBA_DIRECTORIES. Please guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why would *any* user (but a DBA) have access to `DBA_DIRECTORIES`?

Users should have *privileges* to access those directories, i.e. should be granted `read` and/or `write` privileges so that they could

- read files and use them as external tables
- create files using `UTL_FILE`
- export their tables using data pump

and similar. But - access to `DBA_DIRECTORIES` itself? I don't think so.

Comment: @Littlefoot..Not able to understand why we are getting this error...by default user should be able to access the directories however, still we are not able to.

Comment: I think you're wrong. By default, users shouldn't be able to access *anything*. DBA should let them do it. The same goes for anything else; when user is created, it can't even create a table in its schema, until DBA runs `grant create table to jaspreet`. You want to create a sequence? You can't, DBA has to run `grant create view to jaspreet`. You want to access a directory? You can't, until DBA runs `grant read, write on directory ext_dir to jaspreet` (I made up those names; I don't know whether directory or user with such names exist, but - I hope you got the idea). Talk to DBA (again).

Comment: I have checked in all_tab_privs.. Schema name have the read and write access for that particular directory name. But still we r not able to see result from Dba_directories table...

Comment: Please, read once again what I wrote and try to understand what I wrote.

Comment: @Littlefoot: i want to understand, wat is the problem in having read access to "DBA_DIRECTORIES" ?

Comment: If you aren't a DBA, you don't need it. ALL_DIRECTORIES is enough for you. If Oracle thought that everyone should see everything, they'd make it so. You, with your privileges, have access to ALL_DIRECTORIES and that's it. Why do you think that you should be able to view DBA_DIRECTORIES? You just aren't privileged.

Comment: I don't agree to the part  "If you aren't a DBA". I never said it should be by default available but If I talk about my role where we have an ERP system and we have multiple schema within it and I need to develop some base functionality for all e.g upload file functionality based on schema user I may need the information for all directories per schema user.( based on how i implement). Frankly speaking reading dba_* directories is certainly not a privilege only DBA should have.

Comment: Are you able to access all other DBA_* tables such DBA_TABLES ? if not then can you ask DBAs to give you SELECT ANY DICTIONARY grant just to check and then they can revoke or ask them to give you the output of which roles and grants you have.

Comment: True, it is irrelevant what I think about it. But the bottom line is that you don't have the privilege to view its contents and you won't have it until/unless DBA grants it to you. I'm not a DBA, especially not on your database, so there's nothing we (as a community) can do to help you. You'll just have to talk to your DBA (did I say that already? I think I did).

Answer (score 0):

Access to a database directory is done in two steps:

-Database permission : The user must have read and if necessary write privilges over the directory. You can check this by this query

```
select * from all_tab_privs where table_name = 'YOUR_DIRECTORY' ;
```

-If your user has the privileges read and write granted over the directory, but still you are getting errors using UTL_FILE, then perhaps the problem is in the physical location of the directory itself. You must check the privileges of the directory_path in the server

```
select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name = 'YOUR_DIRECTORY' ;
```

Get the path from the above query, go to the server and check that the operating system  user who owns the oracle software has read and write privileges over that folder ( normally is oracle in Linux servers )

You don't need access to DBA_DIRECTORIES, that is only for administrative purposes, as all the DBA views are. You have more than enough with your ALL_DIRECTORIES view

Answer (score 0):

I think we are talking two different things here , having access to directory doesn't guarantee we have the access to dictionary view such as `DBA_DIRECTORIES`.

See [Question answer](https://answers.dynatrace.com/questions/149755/db-agent-why-is-select-catalog-role-required.html#:%7E:text=The%20SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE%20role%20grants%20read,tables%20from%20the%20performance%20views.)

Please read [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_dictionary_select_any_dictionary_and_select_catalog_role.htm)

Check now if you have these rolee.